# Method Illuminate\Support\Str::transliterate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am using:

`Laravel: 9.x-dev`

`PHP: 8.1.5`

`laravel/ui: v3.4.5`

After updating my application from `Laravel 8` to `Laravel 9` I get this error when trying to authenticate.

It references line `92` in `vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\ThrottlesLogins.php`

```
   protected function throttleKey(Request $request)

{

    return Str::transliterate(Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip());

}
```

Comment: A really weird error.. Laravels String helper function don't include a `transliterate` function.. Neither in v9.x nor v8.x...
A fulltext search on Github reveals that this function is not mentioned in any code related to php except a russian Laravel package for cyrillic transliteration.. Maybe create a Issue on the Laravel\Ui Github page?

Comment: Could you maybe post the full error you are getting? I was actually wrong about my assumption it doesn't exists. It is just not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I was also surprised to not find this error anywhere else online. This is the full error I believe. Please let me know specifically if there's something else I can include:

Comment: `BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Support\Str::transliterate does not exist.`

First frame: `Illuminate\Support\Str::__callStatic`

`\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:87` (`throw...`)

`public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)

    {

        if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {

            throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(

                'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method

            ));

        }`

Comment: Second frame: only location which mentions `transliterate`. The line shown in original post inside throttleKey function.

Comment: I would highly recommend creating an issue on the Laravel\Ui Github page. Otherwise, have you tried running `composer update` and `composer install` ?

Comment: I will post there. Thank you. Yes, I have run update and install. Both are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this error by changing Laravel off the `dev` release in composer. In my case going from `9.x-dev` to `9.1.5`

Comment: hey, may i know where's the file that i should change? what is the name of the file

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Try to run this command :

```
composer update
```

Make sure you imported this class ex:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

i hope it was useful

**UPDATE**

now you can use `str()` function directly without importing any class

Comment: The Laravel\Ui Class https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/bc44a9cdce24d36a76dc64e6920e2c966580d659/auth-backend/ThrottlesLogins.php already includes the String support class.

Comment: maybe that's problem just try to import it in your controller

Comment: i tried it in my project and it works , i'm using laravel 8

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. The transliterate function just isn't mentioned in the docs.. I have no clue

Comment: It is already imported in the file as linked by @Laisender. I imported into my LoginController as well and same result persists. Is there another controller I should be looking at?

Comment: Try to run this command : composer update

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to you LoginController.php file

```
/**
 * Transliterate a string to its closest ASCII representation.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @param string $unknown
 * @param bool|null $strict
 * @return string
 */
public static function transliterate(string $string, string $unknown = '?', bool $strict = false): string
{
    return ASCII::to_transliterate($string, $unknown, $strict);
}


/**
 * Get the throttle key for the given request.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function throttleKey(Request $request): string
{
    return self::transliterate(Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by updating laravel/ui to 4.0

> "laravel/ui": "^4.0"

Supported version on the readMe here https://github.com/laravel/ui/tree/4.x